# FG is 10 points under expected. Contamination?

Tags: fermentation, contamination

I brewed an Imperial Stout and was aiming 1.099, but got 1.090 OG (By adding 1 pound of DME)
After 13 days, my FG was 1.022 which was exactly my target.

5 months later, I took a reading and got 1.012.
I tasted it, it's hard to tell if there's an off flavour. Beer is an intense 10.5% ABV having bourbon and wood in it. It's really good, but I don't know if I'm looking too hard to detect something different, after several sip I got a weird feeling that lasted quite a long time.

Might it be contaminated? Dangerous to drink? How to know?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose that with a target FG of 1.022 from 1.099, you would already have a bit lower FG. If I calculate this, however, from 1.099 to 1.022 is an attenuation of 77%. Using this from an OG of 1.090 leads to a FG of 1.020.

There might be another factor playing in this. I noticed with stouts with much roast malts that the yeast does not perform as well, and consequently I had gushers in some of them, but they were still very nice of taste and drinkable.

I think that a real contamination would have brought your final gravity much lower than 1.012 in five months, and that real off-tastes and smell would stand out. Measure your gravity certainly a month further.

As for the weak feeling, can you describe it further? Dizziness? Something else?

Comment: It was a mouth feeling. Maybe some esters I wouldn't expect from a stout. But again, maybe I'm crazy because I had the feeling something happened since FG continued droping after 13 days.